# Configuring Availability group between Two SQL Server Failover Cluster Instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, distributed-availability-groups

I am having two Windows clusters. Two SQL cluster instances are there in each two node cluster (

Data centre 1 :Windows Cluster 1-SQL2016CLUS1

Node 1
Node 2
SQL 2016 failover cluster instance1 -SQL2016DB01
SQL 2017 failover cluster instance2 -SQL2017DB01

Data Centre 2: windows cluster 2-SQL2016CLuS2

Node 3
Node 4
SQL 2016 failover cluster instance1 -SQL2016DB02
SQL 2017 failover cluster instance2 -SQL2017DB02

Now I want to configure "Availability Groups" between two SQL 2016 cluster instances(SQL2016DB01 & SQL2016DB02) 
How to configure it?

For configuring "Distrubuted Always On Availability groups" We need to create AOAG right(with in same data centre)? How to create AOAG, because i have only one instance

Answer (score 1):

You can try a “[distributed availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)”:

> A distributed availability group is a special type of availability group that spans two separate availability groups. The availability groups that participate in a distributed availability group do not need to be in the same location. They can be physical, virtual, on-premises, in the public cloud, or anywhere that supports an availability group deployment. This includes cross-domain and even cross-platform - such as between an availability group hosted on Linux and one hosted on Windows. As long as two availability groups can communicate, you can configure a distributed availability group with them.